# Mask Tensor depending on another Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I would like to mark all matches with the Tensor `t2` in `t1` as `True` otherwise False. An example of such an operations is shown in the example below:

```
t1 = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
t2 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])

mask = tf.some_ops(t1, t2)
print(mask)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(7,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([False, True, True, True, False, False, False])>
```

Given a tensor constant array, how can I create a boolean mask depending on another tensor? (same dimension and the dimension doesn't exceed the first tensor)

I have tried to `tf.math.equal`, but the op expects the same tensor dimensions or a scalar to compare against. Is there such an op to compare against "sub-Tensors"? It seems fairly inefficient to loop over slices of the tensor `t1`.

Comment: What is it you want to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using broadcasting:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
t2 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])

mask = tf.reduce_any(t1[None, :] == t2[:, None], axis=0)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(mask)
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4 5 6], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([False  True  True  True False False False], shape=(7,), dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
t2 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
mask = [val in t2 for val in t1]
print(mask)
>>> [False, True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

If for some reason you need this mask converted to a Tensor you can use `convert_to_tensor`:

```
print(tf.convert_to_tensor(mask))
>>> tf.Tensor([False  True  True  True False False False], shape=(7,), dtype=bool)
```